# bs4 loop stop on the Mid of the links why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a python script bs4 scraper, that scrapes mp4 player links from the web-links I give to it from a text file. The loop runs correctly, but stops in one of the links. Like I pass it below 6 links, they run for 3 and then stop without any errors.

These are the links: [link1](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-1/), [link2](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-2/), [link3](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-3/), [link4](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-4/), [link5](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-5/), [link6](https://ww.anime4up.com/episode/cestvs-the-roman-fighter-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a9-6/)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

text_file = open(r"Python\Anime_Episodes_Links\Links2.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")


num_link = 1

for a in text_file:

    source = requests.get(text_file.readline())

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')


    contener = soup.find('div', {'id': 'episode-watch-content'})

    server_links = contener.find('ul', {'id': 'episode-servers'})

    epi_link = server_links.find('a')['data-ep-url']

    print(str(num_link) + '-' + str(epi_link))
    num_link = num_link + 1


print('DONE')
```

Need help to understand where the issue is in my code, that it does not complete for all 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, I hope this is the outcome you are looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

text_file = open(r"a.txt", "r")

num_link = 1

for line in text_file.readlines():
   source = requests.get(line)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
   contener = soup.find('div', {'id': 'episode-watch-content'})
   server_links = contener.find('ul', {'id': 'episode-servers'})
   epi_link = server_links.find('a')['data-ep-url']
   print(str(num_link) + ' - ' + str(epi_link))
   num_link = num_link + 1

print('DONE')
```

When I ran the program it managed to print 6 links:

```
1 - https://moshahda.online/embed-fk3xtl0vsec3.html
2 - https://moshahda.online/embed-awer88vmgnx7.html
3 - https://moshahda.online/embed-50hnaf9p7qyq.html
4 - https://moshahda.online/embed-2gd52ruefqyt.html
5 - https://moshahda.online/embed-sz2mcl9r1nhz.html
6 - https://moshahda.online/embed-48u0cit7d0ef.html
DONE
```

Comment: Thankkkkk youuuuuuuuu my friend it's run better now Thank you so mach